# VHDL code to read the inputs of a parallel AD converter

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I was wondering if someone could help me to find the error I am making when reading the analog input introduced to the [AD7822](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7822_7825_7829.pdf) converter by a potentiometer capable of varying its voltage in a range of 0 to 5V.

As far as I understand what I have to do is to generate a **20ns** wide pulse for the `CONVST` bit every **10MHz** at most (starting from a clock operating at a maximum frequency of **50 MHz**), then wait for the DR to be set to **0** and the value of the digital inputs could be taken.

[Timeline for working with AD7822 in automatic mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBzRu.png)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity db_read is
    generic
    (
        div : natural := 5
    );


    port
    (
        -- Input ports
        clk_in  : in  std_logic;
        rd          : in  std_logic;
        db_input    : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

        -- Output ports
        convst      : out std_logic := '1';
        db_output   : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others => '0')
    );
    
end db_read;


-- Library Clause(s) (optional)
-- Use Clause(s) (optional)

architecture arch1 of db_read is
begin

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Send CONVST each div/50MHz ms.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    process(clk_in)
    variable cont_convst    : integer range 0 to div := 0;
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk_in)) then
            cont_convst := cont_convst + 1;
            
            if (cont_convst = 1) then
                convst <= '0';
            else
                convst <= '1';
            end if;
            
            if (cont_convst = div) then
                cont_convst := 0;
            end if;
            
        end if;
    end process;
    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Read digital inputs when ready
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    process(clk_in)
    variable cont_rd : integer := 0;
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk_in)) then
        
            -- Detect if RD takes '0' value
            if (rd = '0') then
                cont_rd := cont_rd + 1;
            end if;
            
            if (cont_rd = 1) then
                db_output <= db_input;
            end if;
            
            if (rd = '1') then
                cont_rd := 0;
            end if;
            
        end if;
    end process;

end arch1;
```

When I simulate it on a board what I see is that I always have all the outputs at high state regardless of the voltage that I introduce to the input of the converter.

Comment: I think that `cont_convst` and `cont_rd` should be signals, not variables.

Comment: By "simulate on a board", do you mean loading the synthesized code on an FPGA or running an actual simulator?

Comment: Well, actually both, in the simulator everything seems to work correctly but then when you transfer it to an FPGA the problems appear @mkrieger1

Comment: @mkrieger1 I also change variables to signals but nothing has changed

Comment: Nothing wrong with using variables there (though cont_rd should be ranged, and you need to understand the difference between variable and signal assignment semantics, which WILL matter here). Since simulation works, I would start by simply generating signals on the outputs (like a counter on db_output) and seeing if I can get those through the synth/P&R tools (pin allocation, I/O constraints, clock input pin etc) before going further.